# How to find indexes of words in list?

Tags: python, indexing

So I have a following list:

```
found = ['ITERATION 0', 'string', 'ITERATION 1', 'string', 'ITERATION 2', 'string']
```

I am trying, and I can't for the life of me find any answers from StackOverflow or Youtube, to extract the index of each `ITERATION`.

So in my example the reslt would be `[0, 2, 4]`.

I can use `found.index(r'ITERATION 0')` to find the specific occurrence; but this doesn't help me find `2` and `4`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python

Comment: Sometimes you have to figure out the answer yourself rather than searching for something canned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) with list comprehension:

```
>>> found = ['ITERATION 0', 'string', 'ITERATION 1', 'string', 'ITERATION 2', 'string']
>>> [i for i, s in enumerate(found) if s.startswith('ITERATION')]
[0, 2, 4]
```

In above `enumerate` returns `(index, string)` tuples. For every tuple list comprehension checks if string starts with `'ITERATION'` and if it does includes the index to the result.